# What's the difference in Swift between unowned vs weak but implicitly unwrapped?

Tags: ios, swift, weak-references

```
weak var cat: Cat!
```

vs

```
unowned var cat: Cat
```

Just started getting my head around this topic but this one really confuses me, is there any benefits of using weak but implicitly unwrapped variable in normal setting, other than for UI stuff?

Comment: Unowned just describes logic of your reference - "Unlike a weak reference, an unowned reference is expected to always have a value. As a result, marking a value as unowned doesn’t make it optional, and ARC never sets an unowned reference’s value to nil." https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID52

Comment: This is very well described in the Swift documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID54

Comment: @BenSinclair I went through that but I didn't see an example with 'weak implicitly unwrapped optional'

Comment: @Bruce `weak` and implicitly unwrapped are mutually exclusive; because `weak` can turn `nil`. Either way if you guarantee the lifetime of a variable, then you're better off with `unowned`.

Comment: Ya I thought so too, but I see them in the current code base I'm working on. So if what you said is true, basically both are the same thing but doesn't make sense to use the weak IUO if we guarantee it will never be nil we should use unowned. So to me weak IUO and unowned is the same thing but unowned makes the intention clearer.

Comment: @Bruce Yes. However, at least in Objective-C, weak references are handled differently, i.e there is an actual call to `objc_loadWeak` to load a weak reference. `Unowned` references are likely assigned as is, as if you were to assign a primitive to a variable, since a reference is just an address in memory and `unowned` does not give any guarantees, unlike `weak` which must turn `nil` when the memory is released. So it also should be cheaper in terms of performance to use `unowned` than `weak`, because the compiler or runtime has to keep track of all weak refs so it can `nil` them later.

Comment: cool makes sense, will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can still check an IUO to see if it's nil, even though you don't have to.
2. You have to give an `unowned var` an initial value that isn't just `none`. This is not as meaningful as `none` if the initial value is just a placeholder before it gets a "real" value.